# Is HTTPS meaningful for Jenkins Docker container behind Nginx?

Tags: tls, docker

I have a Docker Compose setup that starts up Nexus, Jenkins and Nginx containers. All calls to Jenkins and Nexus must pass through Nginx.  I accomplish this by only port forwarding the Nginx container.  The Nexus and Jenkins container ports are merely exposed towards the Docker network.

This is my (simplified) `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nexus:
    build: ./nexus/.
    expose:
      - 8081
  jenkins:
    build: ./jenkins/.
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 50000  // no longer needed if Jenkins does not need HTTPS
    depends_on:
      - nexus
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.5
    ports:
      - 80:80  // will also need to port forward 443:443 for HTTPS
    depends_on:
      - nexus
      - jenkins
```

My `nginx.conf` (again simplified):

```
http {
    upstream docker-jenkins {
        server jenkins:8080;
    }
    upstream docker-nexus {
        server nexus:8081;
    }

    server {
        server_name  jenkins.homenetwork.dns;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://docker-jenkins;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name  nexus.homenetwork.dns;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://docker-nexus;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this on my home network and will allow BitBucket to trigger jobs from Jenkins (through Nginx!). This means that the port must be externally accessible.  Obviously Nginx will need to encrypt the incoming urls with HTTPS. So the expected addresses are *https://jenkins.homenetwork.dns* and *https://nexus.homenetwork.dns* with the HTTP versions redirecting to HTTPS.

The question is, do I need to setup Nexus and Jenkins with a SSL certificate?  They are included in many tutorials for setting up Jenkins and Nexus, but the network traffic between Jenkins/Nexus and Nginx should only be visible from the machine that's hosting the Docker containers.  Do I run a security risk somehow by not encrypting the traffic between the Docker containers?

Comment: You could probably save yourself more trouble if you ditched all of this and just used BitBucket pipelines, but that's just me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice I haven't seen that often.  As long as

- the traffic is secure without encryption between the reverse proxy (nginx) and the application (e.g. on the same hardware or safe network); and
- it is OK for you that the nginx instance handles all your network certificates

nginx would handle HTTPS and `proxy_pass` the rest upwards.  This has advantages of speed as well as simplicity in the apps.